# Как убрать index из адресной строки сайта

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как сделать так чтобы вместо адреса `localhost/index` было просто `localhost`
Пробовал разные методы с помощью `htaccess`, но никаких результатов не получил. Стоит Open Server.

Php код:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
    $Page = 'index';
    $Module = 'index';
} else {
    $URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
    $Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    $Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    if (!empty($Module)) {
        $Param = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++) {
            $Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
        }
    }
}

if ($Page == 'index') {
    include('resourse/index.php');
```

И htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^resourse/(.*)$ resourse/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ catalog/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=utf-8' .html .htm .shtml
```

Где ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто:

Дописал в htaccess:

```
Redirect /index /
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант такое правило

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^index$ http://domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Если обратились к `http://domain.com/`, то перейти на `http://domain.com/index.php`? :)

Comment: @Visman ой, пардон ). Исправил кажется так должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в .htaccess строку
DirectoryIndex index.php

Comment: Не сработало. Может имеет значение после чего именно добавлять эту строку?